# In-App purchase transaction fails with SKErrorPaymentCancelled in sandbox mode

Tags: testing, ios7, storekit

**Context**

- Products load correctly via `SKProductRequest`
- Test users setup via itunes connect and verified
- Logged out from my "normal user" account on the device
- Logged in as test user on the device

**Problem**

- The payment transaction fails with `SKErrorPaymentCancelled` without any action from the user
- The app is redirected to the iTunes Store and keeps asking for the user credentials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that I was logging the test user by using the Settings --> iTunes & App Store --> Apple ID.

This process seems to "convert" the test user into a "real user". In fact, you get asked for credit card info and such, as would be expected for a "real user".

The solution is:

- create a new test user
- ensure that no user is logged in the Settings --> iTunes & App Store --> Apple ID
- test the purchase path in your app
- when asked for user credentials, use the newly created user credentials

I hope this saves you time.